# How to set up a progressView for an AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am thinking about using KVO for the Player's currentTime. But the currentTime is a method (`[myPlayer currentTime]`) instead of a property, would the KVO work in this case? If not, how could I track the progress of the video playing and set up a float number for the progressView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the AVPlayer's `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` to get periodic callbacks based on the current time. The current time is passed to your block as its parameter.

Comment: Thanks matt, seems like I should search for official documentation before I ask another question :)